# Handling null values from ResultSet

Tags: javascript, ado

I used the following codes to retrieve values from a database:

```
if( !rs.bof ){
     rs.MoveFirst();
     while ( !rs.eof ){
        output.innerHTML += rs.fields( "Name" ) + ","
        output.innerHTML += rs.fields( "Address" ) + "<br>"
        rs.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

But if the Address is null then it writes:

```
Sherlock Holmes, 221B Baker Street
James Moriarty, null
```

I've tried using:

```
if( rs.fields( "Address" ) != null && rs.fields( "Address" ) != "" )
```

What should I do to make the null values appear as an empty string?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if( !rs.bof ){
     rs.MoveFirst();
     while ( !rs.eof ){
        output.innerHTML += (rs.fields( "Name" ) || "") + ","
        output.innerHTML += (rs.fields( "Address" ) || "") + "<br>"
        rs.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

Use a [logical `Or`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) to change it to an empty string

Comment: @Joseph ,how would it prevent null from printing ?

Comment: @HenryTaylor it should: http://jsfiddle.net/Pc6hW/  Are you sure the `rs.fields( "Address" )` is evaluating to a javascript `null` value or just a string of the value "null"?

Comment: @Furqan The logical or returns the compared value that has a value.  Therefore, if it returns null for rs.fields( "Address" ), it will use ""

Comment: @Joseph It evaluates it as a String, I tried this: `rs.fields( "Address" ) == "null" ? "" : rs.fields( "Address" )` and it worked. Will this be a problem? Cause I won't be able to tell if the value is "null" or if it's just empty

Comment: @HenryTaylor It may be a problem, but really it just depends on how you handle it.  It will largely depend on what the project's requirements and business rules are.

Answer (score 0):

modify the code like this

```
if( !rs.bof ){
     rs.MoveFirst();
     while ( !rs.eof ){
        var name = rs.fields( "Name" ) ;
        var address = rs.fields( "Address" ) ;
        output.innerHTML += (name == null ) ? "" : name  ;
        output.innerHTML += (address == null ) ? "" : address + "<br>" ;
        rs.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a helper function to keep things tidy:

```
function field_maybe(rs, fname) {
    return rs.fields(fname) || "";
}

...

if( !rs.bof ){
     rs.MoveFirst();
     while ( !rs.eof ){
        output.innerHTML += field_maybe(rs, "Name") + ","
        output.innerHTML += field_maybe(rs, "Address") + "<br>"
        rs.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if( !rs.bof ){
     rs.MoveFirst();
     while ( !rs.eof ){
        var name=  (rs.fields( "Name" ) === null)?"":rs.fields( "Name" );
        var address=  (rs.fields( "Address" ) === null)?"":rs.fields( "Address" );
        output.innerHTML += name + ","
        output.innerHTML += address + "<br>"
        rs.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old topic/question but I actually had the same issue, and was dead sure I had done this before. None of these answers seemed appropriate for the actual issue.

The problem is that rs.fields( "Address" ) will never evaluate as null or false.

So if we take OPs evaluation statement:

```
if( rs.fields( "Address" ) != null && rs.fields( "Address" ) != "" )
```

It will indeed always turn up true; you instead need to check the value:

```
if(rs.fields( "Address" ).value){...}
```

if there is none it will return false, unlike the other solutions that all hit the same problem of it always evaluating as true.

Hope it helps anyone else that hits that little problem.     : )